# Отличие диалектного от областного

Tags: лексикография

В чём заключается отличие между диалектизмом и областным словом? В словаре в условных сокращениях увидел две различные пометы: соответственно диал. и обл. Может быть, областное — более узкое понятие, близкое к говору или наречию, а диалект может объединять несколько областей. Может, это связано с тем, что область — политическое образование, а территория — географическое?

Answer (score 1):

"Грамота Ру" [считает](http://gramota.ru/slovari/types/17_4) эти слова синонимами. Что имели в виду составители упомянутого Вами словаря, лично я могу только гадать...